# After Installing Fishpig my blog page redirecting to 404 page in magento2

Tags: magento2, wordpress, integration

I have installed FishPig and configure it from admin, but on my blog page redirecting me to 404 page!!!

[image]

I am using magento2.2.5

Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: @AasimGoriya I can not access Wp folder from out of magento folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to add "wp" in your path field, and make sure that you have added .htaccess file.

Also put your WordPress directory in your Magento root directory.

For more information you can check this URL : https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/installation/

Comment: @RutveeSojitra have you tried this ?

Comment: yes , Can you please give me your wp .htaccess code

Comment: you can create it from here. https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess